# Centos 7 with gnome GUI installed open as root

Tags: root, gui

I am trying out Centos for the first time and I would like to add a context menu or something like it to be able to open a file or folder as admin wile in the GUI.

With Ubuntu I was using gksudo but as far as I can tell this is not a option with Centos. Is that true and if so is there another option?

Answer (score 0):

While I do not consider this a complete answer it is a work around. Instead of logging into the GUI as a normal user just login to the GUI as root.

It would still be better if you could be logged in as none root user and just open a single file or folder as root.

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/267998